# csv generated with asp.net also contains html code

Tags: asp.net, csv, http-headers, httpcontext

I am generating a csv from a  datagrid and downloading it using the code below:

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();            
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                context.Response.Write(csvString);
                Response.Flush();
```

the csv downloads, but below it, there is the html tags of the page. what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

You should call `Response.End()` so that the rest of your page doesn't render after you have sent the csv. In the absence of `Response.End` the page will render normally after this content is sent.

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.ClearHeaders();            
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
context.Response.Write(csvString);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thanx Nunepascal.Another problem though is that response.end() stops execution of any code that comes after, any idea how to bypass that ?

Comment: Well, the idea is to stop the code after that, so that you don't render anything else. What code do you need to execute after the response is over? There are ways to make code execute even after `Response.End`, but it usually hints at something else being wrong.